# Difference between git push --force vs git push non fast forward update

Tags: git

Let us say I run

`git push --force origin master:master` (forced update)

and at another place

`git push origin +master:master` (Non fast forward update)

Are these 2 same ? Any scenario where these 2 behave differently ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are identical. From the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push):

> All of the rules described above about what’s not allowed as an update can be overridden by adding an the optional leading `+` to a refspec (or using `--force` command line option).

However, and perhaps obviously, `--force` applies to everything that's being pushed, whereas `+` applies to only that refspec prefixed with the `+` (`master` in this case). In the two commands in your question, that doesn't make a difference because there is only one refspec in both of them.